# Consume response from a WebClient API call in spring cloud gateway filter exchange

Tags: java, microservices, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-webclient

I am using Spring Cloud Gateway for my microservices and I am trying to make a blocking API call to another microservice within my GatewayFilter. But since spring cloud gateway is reactive, it does not allow for making blocking API Calls so I'm unable to use `.block()` to wait for the WebClient response.
Here is my Auth Filter.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthFilter implements GatewayFilter {

    @Autowired
    private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationTokenService authenticationTokenService;



    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();

        final List<String> openEndpoints = List.of("/api/v1/auth/login","/api/v1/auth/refresh-token","/api/v1/user/register",
                "/api/v1/server/health-check", "/api/v1/user/health-check");
        final Predicate<ServerHttpRequest> isApiSecured = r -> openEndpoints.stream()
                .noneMatch(uri -> r.getURI().getPath().contains(uri));

        if (isApiSecured.test(request)) {
            boolean isAuthorizationHeader = request.getHeaders().containsKey(AUTHORIZATION);
            if (!isAuthorizationHeader) {
                response.setStatusCode(UNAUTHORIZED);
                return response.setComplete();
            }
            try {
                final String authHeader = Objects.requireNonNull(request.getHeaders().get(AUTHORIZATION)).get(0);
                final String[] parts = authHeader.split(" ");
                if (parts.length != 2 || !"Bearer".equals(parts[0])) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Incorrect auth structure");
                }

                if(!request.getURI().getPath().endsWith("/refresh-token")) {
                    final String authenticationToken = parts[1];
                    final AuthenticationTokenDetails authenticationTokenDetails = authenticationTokenService
                            .parseAccessToken(authenticationToken);
                    final Long id = authenticationTokenDetails.getUserId();
                    final String uniqueId = authenticationTokenDetails.getUniqueId();
                    webClientBuilder.build()
                            .get()
                            .uri("http://PERSISTENCE-SERVICE/api/v1/user/verify?id=" +id+ "&uniqueId=" +uniqueId)
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(Boolean.class);
                    //I am trying to consume the response from the above webclient call
                    //The goal is for me to mutate my exchange to include the result from the API call before passing
                    //the request to the downstream microservice
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                response.setStatusCode(FORBIDDEN);
                return response.setComplete();
            }

        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

}
```

I am trying to consume the response from the webclient call. The goal is for me to mutate my exchange to include the result from the API call before passing the request to the downstream microservice

Answer (score 0):

Try to  `.subscribe()` after `.bodyToMono` in order to consume your webclient's response.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general, answers here should not be posed as questions. I've rewritten this on the assumption that you are proposing it as an *answer*.

Comment: However, your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. If possible, please 

[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78235716/edit)

your post to add further details, such as explanations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information in [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) - *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*  It might be helpful to review some highly upvoted answers as examples to follow Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't post a comment as an answer, simply because you do not yet have the comment [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). If you have already taken the [tour] then did you not see: _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site_ and _It's not a discussion forum._